# Как из Python вызывать Rust функцию которая возвращает строку

Tags: python, python-3.x, rust

подскажите как из Python вызывать Rust функцию которая возвращает строку, код:
Python

```
from ctypes import *
import ctypes

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("embed/target/release/embed.dll")
lib.print_text("Hello, from python")
```

Rust

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn print_text2(x: String) {
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Подразумевая, что функция всё же **принимает** строку, а не возвращает и вызов производится через Сишные интерфейсы намеренно, то как-то так:

```
from ctypes import *
import ctypes

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("embed/target/release/embed.dll")
lib.print_text("Hello, from python".encode())
```

Rust:

```
use std::os::raw::c_char;
use std::ffi::CStr;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn print_text(x: *const c_char) {
    println!("Rust writes: {}", unsafe {CStr::from_ptr(x)}.to_str().unwrap());
}
```

---

Более простым способом интегрировать rust-код в python, пожалуй, будет создание python-модуля средствами [PyO3](https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3)

---

См. также:

- [A little Rust with your C](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/book/interoperability/rust-with-c.html#building-a-c-api) в *The Embedded Rust Book*
- [Fundamental data types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types) в документации `ctypes`
- Документацию [`std::ffi::CStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html)